# PHP LDAP Search seems not to be matching *

Tags: php, ldap

Using LDAP Search and a * seems to work fine with words, but with a number it doesn't seem to work:

Debug output from my class (homebrew):

```
Query: Peter is string
Search for cn=Peter
Search for cn=Peter*
Found: 439

Query: 7565 is number
Search for PersonID=7565
Search for PersonID=7565*
Found: 0

Query: 7565025 is number
Search for 
Found: 1
```

Kind of hard to show the code as it is a collection of classes but the part performing the search is using the string after the for:

E.g (this is fabricated)

```
ldap_search($connection, $base, "cn=Peter*", array("dn"));
ldap_search($connection, $base, "PersonID=7565", array("dn"));
ldap_search($connection, $base, "PersonID=7565025", array("dn"));
```

Do you know why the second query on `7565*` returns no results but the last on the full number does return results?

Thanks,

Comment: Your second query doesn't contain any `*` characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably know that on your LDAP Directory, you've got a SCHEMA. SCHEMA is usaly known to provide classes (types) and attributes. But in fact in most Directories the SCHEMA provides two other features for the attributes that are :

1. The syntax of the attribute generaly given by an OID
2. Matching rules that are effectively used to match the attribute

Example :

```
attributeType ( 2.5.4.41 NAME 'name'
                DESC 'name(s) associated with the object'
                EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
                SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
                SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )
```

In the example the matching rules are EQUALITY and SUBSTR that are most of the time linked to the `Directory String` syntax (1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15).

You can encounter the following matching rules :

```
EQUALITY
ORDERING
SUBSTR
```

The matching rule `SUBSTR` is the one generaly used when you write `(cn=Peter*)` filter

So my advice is : have a look on your attribute "PersonID" in your SCHEMA and the "syntax/matching rules" will give you the type of filter you can apply